# using C to generate simple html page with cgi

Tags: html, c, cgi, getenv

C program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main()
{
    char *data = getenv("QUERY_STRING");
    char userName[30];
    sscanf(data,"uname=%s", userName);
    printf ("Content-Type: text/html\n\n");
    printf ("<html>");
    printf ("<head> </head>");
    printf ("<body>");
    printf ("<h2 style=""text-align:center;color=red"";> %s </h2>", userName);
    printf ("</body> </html>");
    return 0;
}
```

HTML:

```
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">

<head>

</head>

<body>
    <form action="echo.cgi" method="get">
        Please enter your name: <input type="text" name="uname">  <br> 
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
</body>

</html>
```

I am trying to use the C program to make a simple html page that just displays the variable uname with GET from html. I am trying to do this by first compiling C to CGI with:

gcc echo.c -o echo.cgi

which it does fine. However, whenever I press submit the cgi file just starts to download. What am I doing wrong

Comment: Looks like a server misconfiguration. Did you configure the CGI interface properly?

Comment: The "get" in your form is something I don't see too often, any chance a Post will fix it?

Comment: Also, it doesn't appear to be a "Content-Length" header, which most browsers are looking for to make the correct decision?

Comment: @fvu not sure what that means, can you explain?

Comment: @PatrickSturm I have to use GET, which uses "QUERY_STRING"

Comment: Is your `echo.cgi` binary under the `cgi-bin` subdirectory?

Comment: CGI runs a *compiled* program.  If you're getting the code you posted above, then you need to compile the code, and point your CGI handler to the compiled file.  If you're getting the compiled file, you might need to mark it as executable.  (What OS are you using?)

Comment: The server sends the file instead of executing it. What server are you using, and where did you store the executable file?

Comment: There does appear to be code missing, for example, where is the "GET 200 OK\r\n" message sent to the client? Should there be a content-length header in this particular case? Content-Type was set well

Comment: I have index.html, echo.c, and echo.cgi all under one directory and am simply running index.html on my browser. I thought that would work but it sounds like I should use Apache server, correct?

Comment: *However, whenever I press submit the cgi file just starts to download.* What exactly do you mean by this? Did you open your browser to `http://server/path/file.html` ? Or are you doing something differently like opening the HTML file locally in a web browser?

Comment: @mcgillian: I don't think you can make CGI scripts work by just loading files directly from your browser (using `file:///foo.html`) like that.  I think you need an actual HTTP server running, it needs to be configured to run CGI scripts (or binaries), and files have to be deployed to the right directories.

Comment: CGI's will indeed only work when served via a server that's capable of running CGI's - like indeed apache. And the CGI subsystem needs to be configured properly, and unless you configure the server otherwise, cgi's will normally be run out of /cgi-bin/

Answer (score 0):

You have to run this through an HTTP server with CGI configured. Simply navigating your browser to your local HTML file on your disk isn't going to execute your code. The server will execute your code and return the output as the response.

Also, I want to point out CGI is a security risk. I realize this is probably just minimal sample code, but because you are not checking the bounds of your string before calling `sscanf`, **you have a vulnerability that someone could exploit to gain access to your server.** https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_overflow